# Why Typescript specification does not contain anything about boolean and number literal types?

Tags: typescript, specifications

It only contains String literal types section without mentioning about other two types.

Also why section "3.8 Specifying Types" doesn't contain anything about literal types at all?

Comment: You're asking us why a website doesn't display some X information?  I doubt anyone on SO will know why it was omitted, only speculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript team has stopped updating the language specification in 2016. Since that time, the language has changed so much that in its current state the specification is almost useless.

There are [numerous issues](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/labels/Spec) about this in TypeScript repo, [here is the comment from the one](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15711#issuecomment-409028030) that summarizes it best:

> There are about four people on the planet who can accurately update
>   the spec and all of them are quite busy already.